# Why doesn't people saving each other make the person they save into a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter

If the protection of love is really what prevented Harry from death and became an accidental Horcrux, then how did James not make Lily an accidental Horcrux? In fact, how did *everyone* who has saved somebody's life by getting in the way not create an accidental Horcrux out of the person they're saving? There'd be Horcruxes, shares of abilities from dozens of people.

Dumbledore says this to Harry in Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 37:

> But I knew, too, where Voldemort was weak. And so I made my decision. You would be protected by an ancient magic of which he knows, which he despises, and which he has always, therefore, underestimated — to his cost. I am speaking, of course, of the fact that your mother died to save you. She gave you a lingering protection he never expected, a protection that flows in your veins to this day.

Well, didn't James die to protect Lily and Harry? I highly doubt that nobody in the Battle of Hogwarts didn't try and save those they loved and died. Wouldn't that have made them a Horcrux to the killer? If it's literally just motherly love, I can guarantee you that somebody attempted to murder a magical mother before with a child. Wouldn't, consequently, people already know that it was motherly love that protected Harry? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I think it had to do with the fact that Voldemort was originally going to spare Lilly, where he wasn't planning to spare James or anyone else at Hogwarts, and Lilly died voluntarily to protect Harry. His lack of intent to kill her specifically, but her getting in the way, is what created the magic protection that Harry had.

Comment: You're confusing the bond of blood charm with the magic of the Horcrux; they're two separate things.

Comment: No sane person would want to make a Horcrux for a beloved person. As Harry Johnston said, you’re confusing entirely different magic. Besides that, there is a difference between just trying to protect someone and making a sacrifice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all: To become a Horcrux there needs to be a part of someone else's soul to attach to you.

It is true that killing weakens the soul and makes it prone to be ripped apart. But without the preparation needed to create a Horcrux it simply will NOT rip apart.
And the preparation is complex, cruel and nothing that anybody would do "just in case..."

The only person in the Potterverse we know doing the preparation to create a Horcrux is Voldemort. And he did it to create a Horcrux on that special evening.

At least Dumbledore was sure, that that was what Voldemort wanted:

> However, if my calculations are correct, Voldemort was still at least one Horcrux short of his goal of six when he entered your parents’ house with the intention of killing you. He seems to have reserved the process of making Horcruxes for particularly significant deaths. You would certainly have been that. He believed that in killing you, he was destroying the danger the prophecy had outlined. He believed he was making himself invincible. **I am sure that he was intending to make his final Horcrux with your death**.
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince, Chapter 23: Horcruxes</sub>

When he killed James he did not intend to create the Horcrux at that moment. Therefore his soul did not split --> He did not create a Horcrux.

When he tries to kill Harry the protection of Lily makes his spell rebound and hit himself. Only this event - being hit by the killing curse - makes his soul split and attach to the only living thing in the room...

> when Lily cast her own life between them as a shield, the **Killing
> Curse rebounded** upon Lord Voldemort, and **a fragment of Voldemort’s
> soul** was blasted apart from the whole, and **latched itself onto
> the only living soul left** in that collapsing building. Part of Lord Voldemort
> lives inside Harry
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33: The Prince's tale</sub>

THAT makes Harry something similar to a Horcrux.

The circumstances were so special, that it is very unlikely for this to happen with any other killing in the Potterverse...

Comment: Also Voldemort's soul was already damaged, having been repeatedly ripped into bits

Comment: Is there any proof that Voldemort prepared to create a Horcrux on that special evening?

Comment: @Holger According to Dumbledore, Voldemort prepared Horcuxes on notable killings. And Harry was the child of a prophecy - definitely notable.

Comment: @Holger: Added quote from HP6 that at least makes it plausible that Voldemort wanted to do this.

Comment: That’s helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that creating an Horcruxes is the exact opposite of the "getting in the way" magic.

With Horcruxes you kill someone you hate (or just don't care) to selfishly save your own life.

The "getting in the way" magic is a selfless and voluntary act of giving your life to save someone else life. (someone that you love)

Seems impossible for someone to do both at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Creating a horcrux requires abilities beyond advanced dark magic. Not only murder but ability to enclose the ripped soul through a spell is necessary. It can be assumed from this there's some pre-horcrux-creation ritual to be done.

> "But how do you do it?"
>
> "By an act of evil--the supreme act of evil. By committing murder. Killing rips the soul apart. The wizard intent upon creating a Horcrux would use the damage to his advantage: he would encase the torn portion --"
>
> "Encase? But how--?"
>
> "There is a spell, do not ask me, I don't know!" said Slughorn shaking his head like an old elephant bothered by mosquitoes. "Do I look as though I have tried it--do I look like a killer?"
>
> **Ch. 23: Horcruxes, Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince**

Voldemort wanted to be immortal. He wanted to create not one horcrux but seven. This doesn't just include a murder but a painful process beyond that - a process of maiming your soul - going against nature of keeping one's soul intact. A partial suicide, if you will. Before coming to kill Harry he had five horcruxes made and that makes for a five times weakened and diminished Voldemort. He had plans to create sixth horcrux after Harry's murder. So he had performed the necessary pre-horcrux-creation ritual to encase his sixth ripped part of the soul.

> "He seems to have reserved the process of making Horcruxes for particularly significant deaths. You would certainly have been that. He believed that in killing you, he was destroying the danger the prophecy had outlined. He believed he was making himself invincible. I am sure that he was intending to make his final Horcrux with your death.
>
> **Ch. 23: Horcruxes, Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince**

But, the curse backfires. Why?

1. Voldemort chose to kill Harry over Neville. In doing so unwittingly he has chosen an equal. It so happens that both of them descend from the Peverell family line. Magic at its deepest, most unfathomable could be at work here.
2. Combine this with a sacrifice so pure and so full of love - you give away your life to protect somebody. In a battle between pure, selfless act and most evil dark magic, goodness wins.  The curse rebounded and his already weakened soul broke yet again, this time caught unaware.

Horcruxes should be hidden and safe. In this case the sixth ripped part of Voldemort's soul latched itself onto the only living thing in vicinity. As the soul's owner had lost form, was less than a living being there had been no spell made yet to encase it in any object. It acted of its own accord, of nature's way. A piece of soul joined what was whole.

Death eaters though vile and evil use Unforgivable Curses. Voldemort performed magic at its most evil while death eaters were atrocious and behaved dastardly. They injured their soul, yes, but not at the cost of experimenting with its wholeness. It should be noted that Voldemort went beyond what others had in the road to immortality. Considering this, he wouldn't have shared the process of creating horcrux to anybody else.

Lastly, horcruxes have to be stored in inanimate objects. It is unwise and risky to create one in a living being that can think and act on its own. That living being could damage itself *or* get damaged by others *or* possibly posses the entire soul.

Without knowing the techniques for creating a horcrux and not choosing an inanimate object to store the ripped soul, it's not possible to create horcrux just by murdering another person.

Answer (score 0):

**Because very few people (including Voldemort) knew about that magic**

You're (partially) right.  If sacrifice is all it took to give someone protection from the killing curse, and Voldemort was throwing them out willy-nilly during his reign of terror, it seems like several people should have survived.  In-universe, there are a few reasons why Harry was the first survivor.

**Family Is Important** - Harry has to live with the Dursleys to keep his magical protection.  Blood relationship is important in the magical world, so just taking a killing curse for your friend won't do it.  It's got to be family.

**Horcruxes are Hard to Make** - Voldemort wasn't just going to kill Harry, he was going to make a Horcrux as well.  Super evil magic + sacrifice = rebound.

**Harry was a Baby** - Being virtuous protects people in fantasy stories (just watch any horror movie).  Harry didn't fight back and certainly didn't deserve to be murdered.

Comment: Harry managed to protect everyone in Hogwarts when he sacrificed himself in Book 7, though?

Comment: That is actually wrong. Voldemort was surely throwing curses all around, but only to Lily he offered the choice to live, if she gives Harry up. She *chose* to die for him, and that's what triggered the protections. Same choice was offered to Harry during the battle for Hogwarts.